# clear OS Block all outgoing traffic unless out to VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, clearos

In clear OS I can block all outgoing traffic. Using Block Mode "Block all outgoing traffic".

This is exactly what I want. However with this mode on I cannot connect to SQL Server via a VPN. I can ping the server by host name, URL, and IP and it responds. But I cannot connect using SSMS until I turned block mode off.

Any thoughts on allowing the SQL server to talk back to VPN clients.

```
               |Internet|
[Me] -> (VPN)--|--------|--> [ClearOS (VPN)] -> [SQL Server]
```

More info:
Clear OS 5.2
PPTP VPN

Comment: If you want to connect to the SQL Server why are you blocking all outgoing traffic?

Comment: This is a triage environment. There are other servers next to the SQL Server that can reach out and erroneously connect to customer's services to collect data. Thus gathering data that the production server should have picked up. So I need to block all traffic to the Internet but not the VPN clients.